# vector pointer locations guaranteed?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Suppose I have a vector of ints,

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
```

that is populated with a bunch of values, then I say do this (where an entry exists at 43)

```
int *oneNumber = &numbers[43];
```

Is oneNumber guaranteed to always be pointing at the int at index 43, even if say I resize numbers to something like numbers.resize(46)?

I'm not 100% sure what expected behaviour is here, I know vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous but not sure if that continuity would also mean all the indices in the vector will remain in the same place throughout its life.

Comment: For this reason I'm always wary of creating a vector of value-types, because I inevitably need a pointer to the objects inside the vector.  So I save a reference like `int* ref = &numbers[43]`.. later do a couple of `push_back`s into `numbers` and WHAMMO!  Bug: `ref` is invalid, because `numbers` has been completely re-allocated and saved in completely different memory space.

Comment: @bobobobo Very true. Though for situations where the number of elements is known at creation time (and no, I can't use `std::array`, because I `emplace`-construct the values by looping), `reserve` guarantees all pointers/iterators into the vector will remain valid, so long as it isn't resized beyond its current capacity (which might force a reallocation and hence moving the addresses of the contained values). This has saved me a few times, but every successive time, I forget to `reserve`, and scratch my head for some time until I remember. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is oneNumber guaranteed to always be pointing at the int at index 43

Yes, this is guaranteed by the standard.

> even if say I resize numbers to something like numbers.resize(46)?

No. Once you resize, add, or remove anything to the vector, all addresses and iterators to it are invalidated. This is because the vector may need to be reallocated with new memory locations.

Comment: What about if you use a `std::list`?  Will that circumvent the invalid address problem if you only use `list.push_back()` calls to add items? (and you don't remove the item that `oneNumber` points to?

Comment: @bobobobo That's a good question. I'm not sure what the standard says about it, but I see no reason that adding/removing to an `std::list` would invalidate any pointers. (except the element that is removed) [We're discussing it in the lounge right now if you wanna join in.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5559322#5559322)

Comment: Found [another workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771369/111307) which I'm currently using.

Answer (score 4):

Your paranoia is correct. Resizing a `std::vector` can cause its memory location to change. That means your `oneNumber` is now pointing to an old memory location that has been freed, and so accessing it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers, references, and iterators to `std::vector` elements are guaranteed to stay put as long as you only append to the `std::vector` **and** the size of the `std::vector` doesn't grow beyond its `capacity()` at the time the pointer, reference, or iterator was obtained. Once it gets resized beyond the `capacity()` all pointers, references, and iterators to this `std::vector` become invalidated. Note that things are invalidated as well when inserting somewhere else than the end of the `std::vector`.

If you want to have your objects stay put and you only insert new elements at the end or the beginning, you can use `std::deque`. Pointers and references to elements in the `std::deque` get only invalidated when you insert into the middle of the `std::deque` or when removing from the middle or when removing the referenced object. Note that iterators to elements in the `std::deque` get invalidated every time you insert an element into the `std::deque` or remove any element from it.

Answer (score 4):

As all the others have said, when you call `.resize()` on a vector your pointers become invalidated because the (old array) may be completely deallocated, and an entirely new one may be re-allocated and your data copied into it.

One workaround for this is ***don't store pointers*** into an STL vector.  Instead, **store integer indices**.

So in your example,

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int *oneNumber = &numbers[43]; // no. pointers invalidated after .resize or possibly .push_back.
int oneNumberIndex = 43 ;      // yes. indices remain valid through .resize/.push_back
```

Answer (score 2):

No - the vector can be reallocated when it grows. Usually once the vector doubles in size.

From the C++11 standard

```
1 Remarks: Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no
reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point
remain valid. If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move 
constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of T or by any 
InputIterator operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown by the move 
constructor of a non-CopyInsertable T, the effects are unspecified.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use a vector's resize() or reserve() function to increase the capacity of the vector, it may need to reallocate memory for the array-backing. If it does reallocate, the new memory will not be located at the same address, so the address stored in oneNumber will no longer point to the right place.

Again, this depends on how many elements the vector is currently being used to store and the requested size. Depending on the specifics, the vector may be able to resize without reallocating, but you should definitely not assume that this will be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Once you changed the capacity of the vector, the data was copied to another memory block, and the origin data is deleted.